# JMSListner in Maven Test Keeps running after Test Completion

Tags: maven-3, spring-jms

```
mvn install
```

When i run my maven tests which Includes starting a JMSListner (Spring-ActiveMQ) , it is stuck after the Listner has thrown a JMSException . I have to manually  kill the Process on Eclipse started by Maven .

How can i confiure the JMSListner so that it is destroyed by Maven after MAVEN TESTs (Junit) have run ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring's JUnit test runner and `@ContextConfiguration` everything will be taken care of you by the framework.

If you are creating the application context within your test, you need to `stop()` the context at the end of text (perhaps in a finally block).